# WooCommerce custom PHP code to change Add To Cart button text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to update the default 'Add To Cart' text to be more suitable for my website. I have created a child theme using Astra, installed it, and then on the Theme Editor in WordPress I added a new function to my functions.php file that should have done the trick

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Check it out', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

From all the examples online it should be this easy. I just read from another post that this may be deprecated now? Should this still work, anything else I can check? I want this to be the button text globally on all products but each product still shows 'Add To Cart'. I saved and then reloaded my website but do not see any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'mujuonly_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'mujuonly_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );

function mujuonly_add_to_cart( $text, $class ) {
    return __( 'Check it out', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

**Tested OK with WC 4.9**

Comment: This worked! Can you explain what was wrong with my approach above?

Comment: You have used only one hook - that was for product archives - the new one I Added is for single product page.